# The react-icons are not loading in my React/TailwindCSS navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS and react-icons, but I can't seem to load the icons used to toggle my menu.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { HiMenuAlt4 } from "react-icons/hi";
import { AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
import logo from "../../images/logo.png";

const NavbarItem = ({ title, classProps }) => {
  return (
    <li className={`mx-4 cursor-pointer ${classProps}`}>
      {title}
    </li>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(0);

  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex md:justify-center justify-between items-center p-4">
      <div className="md:flex-[0.5] flex-initial justify-center items-center" 
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-32 cursor-pointer" />
      </div>

      <ul className="text-white md:flex hidden list-none justify-between items-center flex-initial">
        {["Market", "Exchange", "Tutorials", "Wallets"].map((item, index) => (
          <NavbarItem key={item + index} title={item} />
        ))}

        <li className="bg-[#2952e3] py-2 px-7 mx-4 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#2546bd]">
          Login
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div className="flex relative">
        {toggleMenu ? (
          <AiOutlineClose
            fontSize={28}
            className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)}
          />
        ) : (
          <HiMenuAlt4
            fontSize={28}
            className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setToggleMenu(true)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: It looks like react-icons supports the `size` attribute, but not `fontSize`.

Comment: Please check `md:hidden` className and your width of browser. I think it's hidden on middle wide browser from `md:hidden`.

Comment: react-icons supports the `size` and `font Size` attribute also ... Remove `md:hidden` class and they should appear;-) on each views ...Good Luck.

Comment: @Liberation Warrior, did you resolve this? I do not see a solution posted.